# find total pair of subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

In a subset of  $A=\{1,2,....n\}$ , to find subset with $|A|=k$, we can find using $nCk$

But for $|A \cap B|=k$ such as $\{a,b,c\}$ & $\{b,c,f\}$ when k=2,how can i find the total pair?

For example in $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, subset with $|A|=2$, there are $6$ of them 
$\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,3\},\{3,4\},\{1,4\},\{2,4\}$.

For $|A \cap B|=1$ , there are $12$ pairs $\{\{1,3\},\{3,4\}\} , \{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}\} , \{\{1,2\},\{1,4\}\}, \{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\} ,\{\{2,3\},\{2,4\}\}, \{\{2,3\},\{3,4\}\}, \{\{2,3\},\{1,3\}\} , \{\{1,2\},\{2,4\}\}, \{\{3,4\},\{1,4\}\}, \{\{3,4\},\{2,4\}\} , \{\{1,4\}, \{2,4\}\} ,\{1,3\},\{1,4\}$

How to get total of this pair without count one by one?

Comment: What is $B$ in your example?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If, say, $A\cap B=\{1\}$ then there should be $3$ choices for the other element of $A$ and then $2$ choices for the other element of $B$.  Thus we should have six cases, corresponding to $(2,3),(2,4), (3,2),(3,4), (4,2),(4,3)$. Thus there should be $24$ cases all told, as there are four possible things the intersection might be.  In your list, where is $\{\{1,4\}, \{1,3\}\}$ for instance?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly (far from clear) then if the size of $A,B$ is to be $k_1$ and the size of $|A\cap B|$ is to be $k_2$ then I see the result as the product $\binom n{k_2}\times \binom {n-1}{k_1-1}\times \binom {n-k_1}{k_1-1}$

Comment: Correction:  my formula partially assumed that $k_2=1$.  What I intended to write was $\binom n{k_2}\times \binom {n-k_2}{k_1-k_2}\times \binom {n-k_1}{k_1-k_2}$.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker A and B should be the part of the subsetlike in my example

Comment: @lulu Thankyou, $ \binom {n-k_2}{k_1-k_2}\times \binom {n-k_1}{k_1-k_2}$ , can you explain how do you got this?

Comment: Having specified the $k_2$ elements which comprise $A\cap B$, we now have to build the rest of $A$.  That is, we need to choose the $k_1-k_2$ elements that comprise $A-A\cap B$, then we need to choose the $k_1-k_2$ elements that comprise $B-A\cap B$.

Comment: But, again, this does not match your example.  I get $24$ for your example, with $n=4,k_1=2, k_2=1$.  As I mentioned, it seems to be easy to find pairs that you left off your list, but perhaps I am misunderstanding.

Comment: @lulu do you get 24 because you count (a,b) and (b,a) ?  Can i write $\binom n{k_1}\times  \binom {n-k_1}{k_1-k_2}$?

Comment: Of course I count $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ as two different solutions.  So do you, just inconsistently.  You have both $\{\{1,3\}, \{3,4\}\}$ and $\{\{3,4\}, \{1,3\}\}$ for instance.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry my fault, i corrected it. But i think your answer is right since if i draw the graph , the total degree will be 24. but is it possible only to count $ \binom n{k_2}\times \binom {n-k_2}{k_1-k_2}$? I got the idea that you choose k2 as $A \cap B$  , and to choose the rest for the set will be $\binom {n-k_2}{k_1-k_2}$, why do you still need to count $\binom {n-k_1}{k_1-k_2}$?

Comment: Because I need to populate $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but I interpret it as follows:  Specify three natural numbers, $n, k_1, k_2$. Working in the set $S[n]=\{1, \cdots, n\}$ count the ordered pairs of subsets $A,B\subset S[n]$ such that $$|A|=|B|=k_1\quad \&\quad |A\cap B|=k_2$$

To do so we first count the ways to populate $A\cap B$.  That's just a matter of counting the subsets of order $k_2$ in a set of order $n$, so:  $\boxed {\binom n{k_2}}$.

Having specified the intersection we now need to specify $A', B'$ where $A'=a\in A-A\cap B$ (and similarly for $B'$).

To specify $A'$ we need to draw $k_1-k_2$ elements from $S[n]-A\cap B$.  The latter set has $n-k_2$ elements so there are $\boxed {\binom {n-k_2}{k_1-k_2}}$ ways to specify $A'$.

Now we just need to specify $B'$.  To do so we need to select $k_1-k_2$ elements from $S[n]-A$.  As the latter set has $n-k_1$ elements there are $\boxed {\binom {n-k_1}{k_1-k_2}}$ ways to do that.

Finally the answer is the product:  $$\boxed {\binom n{k_2}\times \binom {n-k_2}{k_1-k_2}\times \binom {n-k_1}{k_1-k_2}}$$

I note that this is not compatible with the example provided in the post, but that example appears to be incorrect (as, in some cases, both $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$ appear but in other cases only one of them does).  Of course, if unordered pairs are desired, you can just divide my formula by $2$.